# Metadata unavailable to layout when rendering

Tags: pug, docpad

So I'm playing with docpad for the first time and have a document that looks like the following

```
--- yaml
title: "Test"
layout: "default"
---
```

And `default.html.jade`

```
html
  title= title
body
  h1= title
  p= layout
  != content
 code= JSON.stringify(locals)
```

But I wind up with a page rendered out without the contents of the title or layout variables.  The dump shows that they are the values I should expect though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was a dumb, the document's metadata can be found in the document object.

I needed `document.title` where I was using `title`

Comment: Right. :) If you could please accept your answer so that this is marked as solved, that would be great. :)